# Triggering Google Home Device to Speak

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, eventtrigger, google-home

Without first speaking to GA, I would like GA to speak to the user based on a triggering event.

I would like to trigger Google Assistant to speak a message based on an event such as a temperature sensor reaching a limit. For example, if the temperature reaches 100 degrees, Google Home would be triggered to say, "Extreme heat warning, please take precautions." Another trigger may simply be a text message from an API that is simply a variable such as var_123 which then triggers the Google Home to speak, "Welcome home, I hope you had a nice day." Push notifications have too many limitations including the rate of notifications that make it impractical to use with sensors that may trigger at a higher rate than permitted.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your Action is continuously running, [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications) are the only solution you have - and, as you note, there are limits with how many get sent and what devices they run on.

Comment: Also, as an addendum, push notifications will not be sent to a Google Home, so such a function would be infeasible.